# How to properly disable and enable input field by option in HTML & JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, forms

How do I properly disable and enable form elements using jquery. I need to enable an input ("#byremaining") when I click on the "remaining" option. When i click the other options the input ("#byremaining") should be disabled again.

```html
<html>

    <head>
    <script src="jq.js"></script>

    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#byremaining').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $(function(){

    $('#remaining').click(function(){
        $('#byremaining').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Sort by:
    <select name="plaats" id="plaats">
        <option value="plaats1">plaats1</option>
        <option value="plaats2">plaats2</option>
        <option value="plaats3">plaats3</option>
        <option value="plaats4">plaats4</option>
        <option value="remaining" id="remaining">remaining</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    date range:<br/>

    Remaining:<input type="text" value="" name="byremaining" id="byremaining"></input><br/>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The remove attribute won't work now and i haven't created the disabled again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#byremaining').prop('disabled', true); //use prop

  $('#plaats').change(function() {
    var selected = $('option:selected', this).attr('id')
    if (selected == 'remaining') { //if selected option is remaining 
      $('#byremaining').prop('disabled', false); //use prop
    } else {
      $('#byremaining').prop('disabled', true); //use prop
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Sort by:
<select name="plaats" id="plaats">
  <option value="plaats1">plaats1</option>
  <option value="plaats2">plaats2</option>
  <option value="plaats3">plaats3</option>
  <option value="plaats4">plaats4</option>
  <option value="remaining" id="remaining">remaining</option>
</select>
<br/>date range:
<br/>Remaining:

<input type="text" value="" name="byremaining" id="byremaining"></input>
<br/>
```

1. Use change event for select
2. Use .prop()

Comment: where is toggle functionality?

Comment: `$('#byremaining').prop('disabled', false);` this part @SatyakiChatterjee use `.prop()`

Comment: Sorry I think this is not toggling.. because if you select remaining then it is enabled but you need to disable this for other selections.. may be I am missing something

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee can you check again?

Comment: @guradio Thanks for the information, it was really useful!! I added something more now, when i click on the others (plaats1, plaats2, etc) then it is disabled again!

Comment: @j.Cup glad to help happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using change event of plaats:

```
$("#plaats").change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val == 'remaining') {
      $("#byremaining").removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
      $("#byremaining").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just toggle the state on the event trigger

```
if($("#byremaining").is("[disabled=disabled]"))
{
    $('#byremaining').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else
{
    $('#byremaining').attr('disabled','disabled');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Disable:

```
("#byremaining").prop("disabled", true );
```

Enable:

```
("#byremaining").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jq.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#plaats').change(function() {
        var i = $(this).val();
        if (i == "remaining")
          $('#byremaining').prop('disabled', false);
        else
          $('#byremaining').prop('disabled', true);
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  Sort by:
  <select name="plaats" id="plaats">
    <option value="plaats1">plaats1</option>
    <option value="plaats2">plaats2</option>
    <option value="plaats3">plaats3</option>
    <option value="plaats4">plaats4</option>
    <option value="remaining" id="remaining">remaining</option>
  </select>
  <br/>date range:
  <br/>Remaining:

  <input type="text" value="" name="byremaining" id="byremaining"></input>
  <br/>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#plaats').click(function(){
         var a =  $('#plaats').val();
            if (a == "remaining") {
                 $('#byremaining').attr('disabled','disabled');
             }
             else
             {
                 $('#byremaining').removeAttr('disabled');
             }
        });

    });


    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Sort by:
    <select name="plaats" id="plaats">
        <option value="plaats1">plaats1</option>
        <option value="plaats2">plaats2</option>
        <option value="plaats3">plaats3</option>
        <option value="plaats4">plaats4</option>
        <option value="remaining" id="remaining">remaining</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    date range:<br/>

    Remaining:<input type="text" value="" name="byremaining" id="byremaining"></input><br/>

    </body>

    </html>
```